# Printing out an array using bulma

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, bulma

I´am having trouble printing out an array when I use Bulma. The array consist of 6 elements. I want to print them out horizontally in there own column, but the are all getting printed out vertically in the same column. I´am pretty new to this, and can´t figure out any soultions. Do I need to change the html code or the js code? Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

HTML:

```
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-multiline">
                <div class="column is-2">
                    <p id="profiler"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++ ) {
            profilerDiv.innerHTML += `
            <h1 class="is-size-5 title has-text-black">${employeeArray[i].name}</h1>
            <h3 class="has-text-black">${employeeArray[i].role}</h3>
            <h3><img src="Bilder/Ansatte/${employeeArray[i].pic}" style="max-height: 300px;" ></h3>
            <p>${employeeArray[i].birtday}</p> 
            <br>
            <br>
            `
            console.log(employeeArray[i]);
         }
```

Comment: [why you shouldn't post image as a code or error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the markup for the HTML column inside your for loop like:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">              
           <p id="profiler"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
for (var i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++ ) {
        profilerDiv.innerHTML += `
        <div class="column is-2">
        <h1 class="is-size-5 title has-text-black">${employeeArray[i].name}</h1>
        <h3 class="has-text-black">${employeeArray[i].role}</h3>
        <h3><img src="Bilder/Ansatte/${employeeArray[i].pic}" style="max-height: 300px;" ></h3>
        <p>${employeeArray[i].birtday}</p> 
        <br>
        <br>
        </div>
        `
        console.log(employeeArray[i]);
     }
```